# nginx: [emerg]: "mail" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Trying to get the basic email of mail reverse proxy working on nginx. I'm using the official nginx docker image and I have the following nginx config setup.

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;

mail {
    server_name       mail.example.com;
    auth_http         localhost:9000/cgi-bin/nginxauth.cgi;

    imap_capabilities IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS IDLE LITERAL+ QUOTA;

    pop3_auth         plain apop cram-md5;
    pop3_capabilities LAST TOP USER PIPELINING UIDL;

    smtp_auth         login plain cram-md5;
    smtp_capabilities "SIZE 10485760" ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 8BITMIME DSN;
    xclient           off;

    server {
        listen   25;
        protocol smtp;
    }
    server {
        listen   110;
        protocol pop3;
        proxy_pass_error_message on;
    }
    server {
        listen   143;
        protocol imap;
    }
    server {
        listen   587;
        protocol smtp;
    }
}
```

After staring nginx with the following command

```
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

I get this error:

```
2017/11/14 22:54:00 [emerg] 1#1: "mail" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9
```

Any suggestion how to resolve this issue?

Comment: `mail` is a top-level block. Check your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file, but I suspect that files in the `conf.d` directory are included into the `http` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for the reply. That is in fact the correct answer. I added the mail block to default nginx.conf and now I am not getting this error. Do you know what is the correct practice here? should I update the default conf?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below line to the first line of `nginx conf` helps me to get rid of this error

```
load_module /usr/ports/www/nginx-full/work/stage/usr/local/libexec/nginx/ngx_mail_module.so;
```

you may want to change the path to suit